# Problem with cursors of python mysql-connector

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I faced a problem connected with mysql-connector in python. Inspite the database is connected successfully and connection's cursor is instance of mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor, any actions with it like .execute() return None.

So query is the last line returns None. Are there any solutions?

````
import mysql.connector
with mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
    user='Tec',
    passwd='TecHeres3141',
    database='abiturients') as db:
    print(db.is_connected())
    cursor = db.cursor()
    print(type(cursor), cursor)
    print(cursor.execute('SELECT CURRENT_TIME();'))```
````

Comment: The ";" in `'SELECT CURRENT_TIME();'` is usually not needed, don't know if that's your problem though

Comment: It definitely doesn't matter.

Comment: you need to fetch the data after execute. print(cursor.fetchone()[0])

Comment: But don't you know why db.cursor() return Any instead of MySQLCursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this line of code: `print(cursor.fetchall())` to get all data that you got with your `cursor.execute()`. For example if you are doing a simple `SELECT * FROM table` you need to use `fetchall()` to get all results and then print it. Also to apply changes to your database use `db.commit()`.